# How to do some aggregate calculation through several columns one by one?

Tags: sql, for-loop, multiple-columns

I am new to SQL and needed some help. I have a table that has some numeric values and I need to populate a column (all values null) with calculations from other columns in the table. 
For example. I have some values and a total value. I need another column to calculate the percentage between those two.

I have many columns that need populating from calculation based on different columns. For eg. A column name "risk1" will help me calculate and populate another column called "1per". My code looks something like this:

```
UPDATE DPRA2_Export
    SET "1Per" = ((CAST(Risk1 AS DECIMAL (38,2))/CAST(GrandTotal AS DECIMAL(38,2))) * 100); 

UPDATE DPRA2_Export
    SET "2Per" = ((CAST(Risk2 AS DECIMAL (38,2))/CAST(GrandTotal AS DECIMAL(38,2))) * 100); 

UPDATE DPRA2_Export
    SET "3Per" = ((CAST(Risk3 AS DECIMAL (38,2))/CAST(GrandTotal AS DECIMAL(38,2))) * 100);
```

.................

It goes on like this.

Is there a way I can for-loop this thing instead of writing over and over again. The only thing that changes in the code is the column name "Risk%" and the SET column name "%Per"

Any ideas?

Comment: How many columns are there on the table?

Comment: Currently there are 5 but it will go up. I wanted a dynamic way of doing this if possible.

Comment: Honestly at that few columns, it'll take longer to write something dynamic than it would to just maintain a standard update statement.

Comment: Do you want to wrap this into something that'll be run automatically, or produce the update statements, then run it manually?

Comment: The number of columns will increment based on regular updates. So I would really like to have the code more general than create a line for every new column that is created. It will potentially run automatically in the future. I am working towards that.

Comment: You can try using EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlupdate . You can dynamicaly create these update statements and using sp_execute try executing each of them in loop

Answer (score 0):

First, having columns with sequential names -- , , . . . -- is suspicious.  In general, this format is not a good fit for relational databases.  Instead, the data should be stored with one row per risk and an identifier for the risk.

Such tables are often useful for *output* purposes, but not for storing data.

Second, the data types for the division are probably entirely unnecessary.  If you are using a database that does integer division and your values are integers, you can convert using a simpler method such as '*1.0'.

Finally, you can issue a single `update`:

```
UPDATE DPRA2_Export
    SET "1Per" = Risk1*1.0 / GrandTotal,
        "2Per" = Risk2*1.0 / GrandTotal,
        "3Per" = Risk3*1.0 / GrandTotal ;
```

You can construct the logic by querying for the columns, using the `information_schema` tables.

Comment: Thanks for that tip! I am still getting the hang of SQL